# ruby YAMLで値の頭が@だとエラーになる件

Tags: ruby, yaml

rubyのYAMLで値の頭が@だとエラーになるのですが、先頭に@を使う方法はありますか？

```
require 'yaml'

p YAML.load(<<EOS)
key: value
EOS 

p YAML.load(<<EOS)
key: @value
EOS
```

実行結果

```
{"key"=>"value"}
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 1 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:252:in `load'
        from test.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

key: "@value" でできました。。。